# Want to add whatsapp to next.js responsive website

Tags: reactjs, next.js, whatsapp, whatsapi

I want to add whatsapp to next.js responsive website. I have put an icon and when icon is clicked on desktop view it opens whatsapp web. which is expected behaviour.

I want if someone is viewing the website on mobile and user clicks the whatsapp icon it should open installed whatsapp app instance.

The code which I have written, it is opening whatsapp website when clicked in mobile view.
Below is the code.

```
'use client'

import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import { FaWhatsapp } from 'react-icons/fa6'


const Whatsapp = () => {

  const router = useRouter();

  const handleClick = async () => {

    // Check if WhatApp installed, if yes open whatsapp else open whatsapp web

    if (navigator.userAgent.includes('WhatsApp')) {
      // WhatsApp is installed
      window.open(`whatsapp://send?phone=8879xxxxxx`)
    } else {
      // WhatsApp is not installed, open WhatsApp Web
      window.open('https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=8879xxxxxx', '_blank');
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='bg-green-600 w-min p-2 rounded-full fixed 
          bottom-10 right-4 cursor-pointer md:right-8' onClick={handleClick}>
        <FaWhatsapp color='white' className='w-7 h-7 md:w-10 md:h-10' />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Whatsapp
```

Comment: wa.me link works for me, but it depends on the browser settings (on Firefox for Android, I must enable Open links in apps in Firefox setting) and if the app is allowed to handle that link in the Open supported links setting, on Android the official app only cover wa.me and api.whatsapp.com, not web.whatsapp.com.  Android 12 also has extra permission requirement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610523/whatsapp-sendtext-doesnt-work

Comment: I have tried using wa.me as well but when clicked it is opening chrome browser installed in mobile phoen instead of whatsapp

Comment: What is your Android version, is this the official Whatsapp client or those "enhanced" version, and does the following link open in WA? https://wa.me/41798931892 (it's WHO Covid bot)

Comment: Link you have shared I tried to open it in mobile browser and got redirected to whatapp app. I tried putting my own phone number instead of WHO covid bot and it returned a pop up with country code missing error. so tried with putting country code and it redirected to whatsapp. so it working now after putting country code

Comment: it is working only when i manually put this wa.me link in browser manually. If I use this link in window.open('https://wa.me/8879xxxxxx'). it opens the browser and redirects to whatsapp website

Comment: do you use https:// in the wa.me link?

Comment: yes I am using https://

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.userAgent` will not tell you whether a user has Whatsapp installed on their device. It would be a security issue if any website could find out the apps installed on a user's device. It only returns [the user agent string for the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgent).

You could use the wa.me links which automatically redirect / prompt the user to redirect to the app ([see docs for wa.me links](https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934/?helpref=uf_share)). I would recommend this since this handles a lot of different scenarios including desktop app ones itself.

Another way would be to use the `whatsapp://` links but after confirming the device type. Something like this:

```js
const isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") !== -1;
```

You can find a bunch of approaches listed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43357241/10509081) stackoverflow answer.

Do note that in the wa.me links you should add the country code without any leading zeroes or `+`.

Comment: I have chnaged my code little bit

 const handleClick = () => {


    if (!isMobile || !isAndroid) {
      window.open(`https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${phone_no}`)
    } else {
      // window.open(`https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=${phone_no}&text&type=phone_number&app_absent=0`)
      window.open(`https://wa.me/${phone_no}`, '_blank')
    }

  }

But here now it is behaving properly on android devices i.e. if clicked button in mobile it is opening installed whatsapp but on iphones it is opening whatsapp.com website

Comment: @MandarDeshpande The code I've shared is to detect if the device is Android. To detect if it is an iOS device, you may need different checks. Refer to [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9038625) for some ideas.